# infomatica unconnected lookup invalid symbol reference error

Tags: informatica-cloud

I am getting invalid symbol reference for below expression in informatica cloud 
decode(true,STAGE_NAME_CODE='S1',:LKP.Lkp_SFDC_description(CODE),0)

in the unconnected lookup i have three fields code,code_type and description, I want to return description for stage_name_code from source file from the unconnected lookup field Code

but he onlytime the expression is valid is when its written like this..
decode(true,STAGE_NAME_CODE='S1',:LKP.Lkp_SFDC_description(STAGE_NAME_CODE))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using DECODE, you can use **IIF** function.

```
IIF(STAGE_NAME_CODE='S1',:LKP.Lkp_SFDC_description(STAGE_NAME_CODE))
```

This provides you an exact result.
To have fun on ETL, play with https://etlinfromatica.wordpress.com/